# Tabulate the columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, function, tabulate

I have this piece of code that calculates the vector "week1" (predefined in the exercise), based on the number of times a value is repeated in that column.
I would need to create a function that does the same for the other 6 columns (from 2 to 7), using the function apply, but I struggle a bit with functions yet.

This is the piece of code:

```
    matrix <- matrix(1, 16, 7)

    week1 <- matrix[,1]
    times <- tabulate(week1, 4)
    vectorW1 <- c(1/times[1], 1-1/times[1], 1/times[2], 1-1/times[2],
        1/times[3], 1-1/times[3],1/times[4], 1-1/times[4])
```

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: Try `apply(matrix, 2, tabulate, nbins = 4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea what this code is trying to do, nor what the target function is attempting to do.

First, let us make it into a function

```r
mat_to_weights <- function(data) {
  stopifnot(inherits(data, "matrix"))
  result <- matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = ncol(data))
  for (col in seq_len(ncol(data))) {
    
    week <- data[, col]
    week
    times <- tabulate(week, 4)
    times
    vector <-
      c(
        1 / times[1],
        1 - 1 / times[1],
        1 / times[2],
        1 - 1 / times[2],
        1 / times[3],
        1 - 1 / times[3],
        1 / times[4],
        1 - 1 / times[4]
      )
    result[,col] <- vector
  }
  result
}
mat_to_weights(data = matrix)
> mat_to_weights(data = matrix)
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]
[1,] 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625
[2,] 0.9375 0.9375 0.9375 0.9375 0.9375 0.9375 0.9375
[3,]    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf
[4,]   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf
[5,]    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf
[6,]   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf
[7,]    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf    Inf
[8,]   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf   -Inf
```

Next, instead of a matrix with 1s, let us try to use dummy matrix from `pracma::magic(n)`.

```r
> mat_to_weights(data = pracma::magic(1))
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    0
[3,]  Inf
[4,] -Inf
[5,]  Inf
[6,] -Inf
[7,]  Inf
[8,] -Inf
> mat_to_weights(data = pracma::magic(2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1  Inf
[2,]    0 -Inf
[3,]  Inf    1
[4,] -Inf    0
[5,]  Inf    1
[6,] -Inf    0
[7,]    1  Inf
[8,]    0 -Inf
Warning message:
In pracma::magic(2) : There is no magic square of order 2.
> mat_to_weights(data = pracma::magic(3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  Inf    1  Inf
[2,] -Inf    0 -Inf
[3,]  Inf  Inf    1
[4,] -Inf -Inf    0
[5,]    1  Inf  Inf
[6,]    0 -Inf -Inf
[7,]    1  Inf  Inf
[8,]    0 -Inf -Inf
> mat_to_weights(data = pracma::magic(4))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  Inf  Inf  Inf    1
[2,] -Inf -Inf -Inf    0
[3,]  Inf    1  Inf  Inf
[4,] -Inf    0 -Inf -Inf
[5,]  Inf  Inf    1  Inf
[6,] -Inf -Inf    0 -Inf
[7,]    1  Inf  Inf  Inf
[8,]    0 -Inf -Inf -Inf
> mat_to_weights(data = pracma::magic(5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  Inf  Inf    1  Inf  Inf
[2,] -Inf -Inf    0 -Inf -Inf
[3,]  Inf  Inf  Inf    1  Inf
[4,] -Inf -Inf -Inf    0 -Inf
[5,]  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf    1
[6,] -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf    0
[7,]    1  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf
[8,]    0 -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf
```

Again, not clear this is supposed to do, but the function works.

Let us rewrite it with apply in mind.

```r
mat_to_weights <- function(data) {
  stopifnot(inherits(data, "matrix"))
  result <- matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = ncol(data))
  apply(data, 2, function(week) {
    times <- tabulate(week, 4)
    vector <-
      c(
        1 / times[1],
        1 - 1 / times[1],
        1 / times[2],
        1 - 1 / times[2],
        1 / times[3],
        1 - 1 / times[3],
        1 / times[4],
        1 - 1 / times[4]
      )
    vector
  })
}
```

Other implementations to consider are of course `sweep`, but for now this works..

Comment: Thank you! What I wanted is to create a function which aim is to create the predefined vector, to be able to apply it to all the columns. The function 'week' is exactly what I needed. I am not very familiar with functions, but it helped me a lot  (and it seems much easier than what I thought!).